# What are the differences between C# Local Functions vs JavaScript Nested Functions?

Tags: javascript, c#, difference, c#-7.0, nested-function

In C#, a Local Function is such:

```
public int MyFunction(int parameter)
{
     int local = 6;
     return MyLocalFunction(4);

     // Local Function
     int MyLocalFunction(int localFunctionParameter) => 42;
}
```

And in JavaScript, a Nested Function is:

```
function MyFunction(parameter) {
    var local = 6;
    return MyNestedFunction(4);

    // Nested Function
    function MyNestedFunction(localFunctionParameter) {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Besides syntax, are there any performance differences between the two of them?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: I don't know how to do stopwatches in either languages. Even still, there's some cases where one thing will always be faster than the other. The main point in this anyways was just to show the difference that I found interesting.

Answer (score 3):

C# and JavaScript handle their nested/local functions differently.

With your example, C# will turn compile this code:

```
public int MyFunction(int parameter)
{
    int local = 6;
    return MyLocalFunction(4);

    // Local Function
    int MyLocalFunction(int localFunctionParameter) => 42;
}
```

Into this code:

```
public int MyFunction(int parameter)
{
    int num = 6;
    return <MyFunction>g__MyLocalFunction|0_0(4);
}

[CompilerGenerated]
internal static int <MyFunction>g__MyLocalFunction|0_0(int localFunctionParameter)
{
    return 42;
}
```

As you can see, `<MyFunction>g__MyLocalFunction|0_0` is cleverly not "inside" `MyFunction`, just in the containing class. This makes them fundamentally different than Nested Functions in more than just their name, I'd say. It does, however, prevent us from using that local function outside the parent function, which is really the end goal.

JavaScript actually recreates its function instance every time it's called, which is bad for performance, as well as unnecessary. I did find a way to prevent that behavior. You would take your JavaScript example and rewrite it as something like:

```javascript
var MyFunction = (function(parameter) {

    return function(parameter) {
        var local = 6;
        MyNestedFunction(4);
    };

    function MyNestedFunction() {
        return 42;
    }
}());
```

Which to me is clunky and isn't the way I want to think about local/nested functions. The syntax isn't as intuitive as C#'s.

Local functions, because they do end up getting moved outside the class, default to the desired behavior of never being instanced twice, so it's the best of both worlds. It has the more natural syntax and better performance (even if just by a little).

Comment: I found that from a StackOverflow answer. The difference is what goes on behind the scenes. It's supposedly makes it so that `MyNestedFunction` isn't created every time `MyFunction` is called, thus being better on performance.

Comment: Sorry, I misread it. In my defense, it was because the `local` is in the wrong place. =) (Also, are you sure JavaScript engines never optimize this when the function doesn’t escape?)

Comment: Oh, woops  I never got this far in JavaScript, so I'm just taking that guys word for it. Where should `local` go then? Ontop of the call to `MyNestedFunction`?

Comment: Right. The `function () { … }` being returned is the actual implementation of `MyFunction`, and the outer IIFE (which doesn’t need `parameter`) is only there to create a scope that hides `MyNestedFunction`. You could also write it like this nowadays – https://gist.github.com/ryan-copperleaf/af29c72f1712abb4d2a0aad8a8c6625b?ts=4 – which achieves the same effect and preserves the name of the function, all with less syntax, at the expense of repeating the name of the function.

Comment: In the example, `parameter` was in the `return function()`, but that seemed like a typo to me. Is that really where it belongs? And that syntax is much better, but it's still not as clean as C# where the syntax much closer matches my intent.

Comment: That’s really where it belongs (and you should remove it from the outer function). The outer function runs and is discarded. As far as being clean: ideally it would just be optimized and you wouldn’t have to do any of this. Maybe it isn’t, though. The typical thing to do in JavaScript would be to make them both module-scope functions and not export the “local function”.

Comment: Then where would it be if it's outside the outer function? I feel like that defeats the whole point of it. Are you saying that the nested functions aren't that common in JavaScript? I never liked the idea of them, until I used local functions and C# and saw the appeal.

Comment: Yes, I’m saying nested functions that don’t escape the function and don’t use any locals aren’t that common in JavaScript.